# Android Studio and Subversion: Cannot import into repository

Tags: android-studio, svn

Android Stdio version: 2.3
SVN: Installed SVN for windows. The command line client works fine.

SVN repository hosted by and located at DreamHost:

Domain: dev.bugrit.net
www: Remove WWW: Make www.dev.burgrit.net redirect to de.bugrit.net

SVN repository:
http://dev.bugrit.net/svn/android/

In Android Studio, I try to VCS -> Import into version control -> import into Subversion

Then I add the repository URL, and I get this error:

[image]

When I try importing a test folder to the same reposiory with TortoiseSVN, I also get an error:

```
Error     Repository moved permanently to 'http://dev.bugrit.net/svn/android'
```

I don't get this? It's the same URL.

This is a completely new, unused SVN repository, and a completely new installation of Android Studio that has never been connected to SVN or any other version contrtol system.

PS: Thanks for the upvotes, so I can upload images and enter links :-)